# Incrementing multiple letters

Tags: java, for-loop

Im having trouble with this code, it keeps repeating the same thing 27 times rather than converting each time. So if the user enters "ASDFG", it repeats "BTEGH" every time

```
import java.io.* ;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class what
{
public static void main (String[] args)
{
Scanner hey = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
String w = hey.nextLine();
System.out.println(w);
int j=0;
while(j<28){
for(int i=0; i<w.length(); i++)
{
  char ch = w.charAt(i);
  ch++;
  System.out.print(ch);
}
j++;
System.out.println();
}
}}
```

Comment: You can append the chars into a string, and for each while step, print the string and replace the w variable with the string previous. However, take in account that is a predictable behavior. :)

Comment: @sgmart This is probably a school assignment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're never actually changing the characters in your `String`. If you want to actually change the character in your `String` in addition to printing out the incremented characters, then you can use `setCharAt()` from [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html), ie:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(w);
```

Then in your loop, you can do:

```
for(int i=0; i < sb.length(); i++)
{
  char ch = sb.charAt(i);
  sb.setCharAt(i) = ++ch;
  System.out.print(ch);
}
```

Comment: Yeah i guess i never was changing the string. Thanks

Comment: @user2968215 Yup.  No problem.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

The while loop is causing the code to repeat 27 times. If you'd like to just convert the string entered by the user one time, remove the while loop.

```
Scanner hey = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Enter a word: ");
String w = hey.nextLine();
System.out.println(w);

for (int i = 0; i < w.length(); i++) {
  char ch = w.charAt(i) + 1;
  System.out.print(ch);
}
```

Comment: Its supposed to be some sort of encryption/decryption program, so it's supposed to display 27 times, each time being something different. And one of the outputs should be something readable

Comment: You aren't saving the chars back into the string then.